# Elasticsearch with multiple parent/child relationship

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building an application with complicated model, says Book, User and Review.

A Review contains both Book and User id. 
To be able to search for Books that contain at least one review, I've set the Book as Review's parent and have routing as such. However I also need to find Users who wrote reviews that contain certain phrases.

Is it possible to have both the Book and User as Review's parent? Is there a better way to handle such situation?

Note that I'm not able to change the way data is modeled/not willing to do so because the data is transfered to Elasticsearch from a persistence database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know you can't have a document with two parents.

My suggestion based on [Application-side join chapter of Elasticsearch the definitive guide](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html):

- Create a parent/child relationship `Book`/`Review`
- Be sure you have `user_id` property in `Review` mapping which contain the user id who wrote that review.

I think that covers both uses cases you described as follows:

- `Books that contain at least one review` It can be solved with has child [filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-filter.html)/[query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html)
- `Users who wrote reviews that contain certain phrases` It can be solved by querying to reviews with the phrase you want to search and perform a [cardinality aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) on field `user_id`. If you need users information you have to query your database (or another elasticsearch index) with the ids retrieved.

Edit: `"give me the books that have reviews this month written by user whose name started with John"`

I recommend you to collect all those advanced uses cases and denormalize the data you need to achieve them. In this particular case it's enough with denormalizing the user name into `Review`. In any case elasticsearch people has written about managing relations [in their blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch) or [elasticsearch the definitive guide](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relations.html)

Comment: Thanks, however the data is relatively big, so application-side join is what I'm trying to avoid. With advanced queries such as: "give me the books that have reviews this month written by user whose name started with John"? Doing application-side join would result in fetching all the user whose name started with John and passing those ids in a terms filter?

Comment: @tungd I completed my answer and added a couple of references that you might find interesting

Comment: I already read those articles. As noted in the question, I'm unable to change the data models. I guess application-side join is the only way to go. I'm also looking at the "lookups" feature of "terms" filter. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Somths like (just make Books type as parent for Users and Reviews types)

```
.../index/users/_search?pretty" -d '
    {
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "has_parent": {
                                "parent_type": "books",
                                "filter": {
                                    "has_child": {
                                        "type": "Reviews",
                                        "query": {
                                            "term": {
                                                "text_review": "some word"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    '
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two options

> Elasticsearch Nested Objects
>
> Elasticsearch parent&child

both are compared and evaluated nicely [here](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/)