# Denormalization vs Child/Parent & Nesting

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, filtering, normalization, nosql

We are designing Elastic Search model for events, their schedules and venues, where the events take place.
The design is following:

[image: model]
Example of queries we might need:

> Find events, which are Concerts, between 1/7/2017 and 7/7/2017
>
> Find artists who performs at London and the event is Theatre play
>
> Find events, which are Movies and having Score > 70%
>
> Find users, who attend event AwesomeEvent
>
> Find venues, which locality is London and any event is planned in the future since today

I've read [elastic doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relations.html) and few articles like [this](https://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/) and some stack [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899494/elasticsearch-with-multiple-parent-child-relationship). But still I'm not sure about our model, because it's very specific.

Examples of possible usage:

1) Using nested pattern

```
{
  "title": "Event",
  "body":  "This great event is going to be...",
  "Schedules": [ 
    {
      "name":    "Schedule 1",
      "start":   "7.7.2017",
      "end":     "8.7.2017"
    },
    {
      "name":    "Schedule 2",
      "start":   "10.7.2017",
      "end":   "11.7.2017"
    }
  ],
  "Performers": [ 
    {
      "name":    "Performer 1",
      "genre":   "Rock"
    },
    {
      "name":    "Performer 2",
      "genre":   "Pop"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Pros:

1. More flat model which should stick to "key:value" approach
2. Entity carries all information by itself

Cons:

1. Lot of redundant data
2. More complex entities

2) Parent / Child relation between following entities (simplified)

```
{
  "title": "Event",
  "body":  "This great event is going to be...",
}

{
  "title": "Schedule",
  "start":   "7.7.2017",
  "end":     "8.7.2017"
}

{
  "name":    "Performer",
  "genre":   "Rock"
}
```

Pros:

1. Avoiding to duplicate redundant data

Cons:

1. More joins (even the parent/child are stored at same [shard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/indexing-parent-child.html))
2. The model is not that flat, I'm not sure about the performance

So far we have a relational database, where the model works fine but it's not fast enough. Especially for example when you imagine a cinema, one event(movie) can have a thousands of schedules in different localities and we want to achieve very fast response for filtering as I wrote at the first part.

I expect any suggestions leading to properly designing the data model. I will be also glad for reviewing my assumptions (probably some of them might be wrong).

Comment: You are unclear. What "model"(s)? What "denormalization"? What "assumptions"? You seem to have 2 designs--non-elastic (relational) & elastic. Please give them. Explain how you will use them. You seem to have two "problems"--one leading to elastic & one with elastic "denormalization". Please explain them. Give your motivating assumptions/expectations/tradeoffs. PS Please edit away your many unclear sentences and unexplained connections. Eg "When I'm thinking...I'm worried...", "Also to me...", "Like...", "practically storing all the data in the elastic" & "copying lot of redundant info".

Comment: Thank you for response. I've added simplified model, also (I hope) specified way more clearly what are models I've been thinking of and added some examples. I also edited away the unclear sentences. Thanks for feedback

Comment: Not sure if you already read this but [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child.html) that is deeply linked in the article you posted gives a pretty good summary of why you may choose either nested vs parent/child relation. Is that helpful? Or is there something that you feel that article is missing?

Comment: Much better. I don't know what (pseudo-)ER information modeling and/or database design method you intend to follow, but that diagram has two unnamed M:M associations/relationships so it's not clear how to map them to tables, and you don't say how to map the M:1s either. Ie you didn't give a complete relational schema. Please give one. (Typeless is shorter.) Including CKs & FKs & any other constraints. PS Use text whenever possible in questions, ie if you gave the preceding then the diagram would be redundant.

Comment: Once you are relatively clear, the problem with your question, like all "best" questions, is  that given costs & benefits & architecture the only way to say which of two designs for what situations is better is to try them. And typically the "better" function is chaotic--a small change can make a big difference--so that that pair of points tells you very little about any other pair. (I like to say, *you* need to tell *us* what you mean by "best" (like with *any* technical term) & we might be able to tell you what likely is--except that a *practical* "best" is both complex *and* chaotic.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to denormalize your data. For example, the number of performers in an event is unknown; so if you were to have specific fields for performers, you would need perofrmer1.firstname, perofrmer1.lastname, performer2.firstname, performer2.lastname, etc. However if you use nested field instead, you would simply define a nested field Performer under event index with correct sub-field mappings, then you can add as many as you want to it. This will enable you to lookup event by performer or performer by event. The same apply to the rest of the indices.

As far as parent-child vs nested, parent-child provide more dependence as child documents reside on a completely separate index. Both parent-child and nested fields can specify "include_in_parent" option to automatically denormalize the fields for you