# Can nested documents have multiple parents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently found several references that nested documents can have multiple parents 
http://vesess.com/elasticsearch-for-hiveage/

https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-performance-considerations-parent-child-relationships

But I don't find any reference to this in the docs.  It seems that there would be only one (I understand I could index the same document twice, but I wouldn't think that's the intent.)

Can someone confirm, deny, or qualify this claim that nested documents can have multiple parents?

Comment: Multiple parent is not possible https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multiple-parents-in-parent-child-mapping/38769/6.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899494/elasticsearch-with-multiple-parent-child-relationship  may be they are referring to having grand parent as a parent

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for a child to have multiple parents. Parent child is 1 to N relation.

A child can have also other child, but each document has at maximum one parent.